# How Can I make these two Divs into these shapes using css and html only?

Tags: html, css, shapes

[These are the Divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XigkR.png)

I tried to use :

```
`clip-path:polygon()`
```

But the shapes have more than 12 Edges, I promise that I've been trying to figure it out for a long period of time and I'm Stuck ..

Comment: http://csshexagon.com/ would this work for you

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/ all the other shapes as well

Comment: http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: Thanks MehravishTemkar but as you can see in the picture the shape has more than 12 edges.

Comment: You can make custom polygon with the link i shared

Comment: thanks @Nimish I tried that but the max edges in that website is 12edges and I need more than that.

Comment: With the custom polygon you can make polygon of many edges. I tried just now

Comment: @Nimish I just made one too but it doesn't have a perfect radius

Comment: @ok I see what you mean I will try it, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use SVG
https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_polygon.asp

I would recommend using SVG's. They are sharp and also endless scale able because they are vector based.

Answer (score 0):

You can use create polygon using this link: http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Create simple triangle and try to understand the % values following the colour dots and percentage and then you can change % values later on to create any polygon.

```css
div {
 width: 280px;
 height: 280px;
 background: #1e90ff;
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 80% 10%, 100% 35%, 100% 70%, 80% 90%, 50% 100%, 20% 90%, 0% 70%, 0% 35%, 20% 10%);
clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 80% 10%, 100% 35%, 100% 70%, 80% 90%, 50% 100%, 20% 90%, 0% 70%, 0% 35%, 20% 10%);
}

/* Center the demo */
html, body { height: 100%; }
body {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```